# Ng-bind-html not working with custom components

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am using typescript with Angular. My requirement is to dynamically fill the contents of the tab.

I have a variable which has HTML content with Angular components included using `ng-include`.

I m using this variable in my HTML inside `ng-bind-html` tag. It is not recognising the Angular tags.

I'd I just use Normal HTML tags, it compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your plunker, Angularjs is never included, you don't have ng-app directive at the top, so I don't see how it can recognise anything related to Angularjs